how should I test @authentificationprincipal?
I got   @PostMapping("/login")
public String postLogin(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
authService.auth(userDetails.getId());
return "redirect:/main";
} and test method:   @Test
void postLogin_success() throws Exception {
UserDTO userDTO = createUserDTO(1, "User", "user@mail.ru", "password");
    when(authService.auth(anyInt())).thenReturn(userDTO);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/login")
                    .with(csrf())
                    .principal(authenticationToken)
                    .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                    .param("email", "user@mail.ru")
                    .param("password", "password"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/main"));
} but it shows an error: java.lang.AssertionError: Redirected URL expected:</main> but was:</login?error>

Expected :/main
Actual   :/login?error

If Spring Security's authentication fails, userDetails will not be injected, and Spring Security will redirect to the failure URL (/login?error). Perhaps your test setup does not authenticates correctly? Try to log in your controller if you even reach there (if you do auth works). Then check/debug what your authService (authService.auth(userDetails.getId())) does.
